# How to include file in PHP with user defined variable

Tags: php, html, include, str-replace, file-get-contents

I am trying to include file in string replace but in output i am getting string not the final output.

**analytic.php**

```
<?php echo "<title> Hello world </title>"; ?>
```

**head.php**

```
<?php include "analytic.php"; ?>
```

**index.php**

```
string = " <head> </head>";
$headin = file_get_contents('head.php');
$head = str_replace("<head>", "<head>". $headin, $head);
echo $head;
```

**Output i am getting :**

```
 <head><?php include "analytic.php"; ?> </head>
```

**Output i need :**

```
 <head><title> Hello world </title> </head>
```

**Note :** Please do not recommend using `analytic.php` directly in `index.php` because `head.php` have some important code and it has to be merged `analytic.php` with `head.php` and then `index.php`

Comment: `file_get_contents` _only_ reads the file content, it does not put that content through the PHP parser.

Comment: Why not just do `<head><?php include "head.php"; ?></head>`? Please show me the detail if you can't.

Comment: @shingo `analytic.php` have analytic code from Google analytic, Microsoft clarity, and other analytic. `head.php` have many code including javascript and css linking. All are in different folder. 

So, i am trying to include all the analytic code in `head.php` and than `head.php` in `index.php`

Comment: @CBroe yes i know. even i cannot do `$headin = include "analytic.php";` . What is the solution to it?

Comment: But that didn't explain why you cannot include `head.php` in `index.php`.

Comment: `string = " <head> </head>";` Invalid PHP. Could that be the problem? Or a TYPO

Comment: @shingo because `head.php` have all the files such as `css`, `javascript` and analytic code from `analytic.php`. not including `head.php` in `index.php` will break the website

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, it typo mistake. i am not getting any `php error`. Instead of including values from `analytic.php`. it including the string `<?php include "analytic.php"; ?>` in `index.php`

Comment: _"even i cannot do `$headin = include "analytic.php";`"_ - that would only work (to populate $headin with any other value than the default 1 or false), if `analytic.php` was actually _returning_ anything in the first place. All explained in detail under https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: From the examples in the question, there's only one line in **analytic.php** and **head.php**, and you tried to fill the content of **head.php** into index.php. But from the comments you told me there are more contents in these 2 files. So the problem now seems not as simple as what you described above. Please polish it with what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To get the desired output :**

```
function getEvaluatedContent($include_files) {
    $content = file_get_contents($include_files);
    ob_start();
    eval("?>$content");
    $evaluatedContent = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $evaluatedContent;
}

$headin = getEvaluatedContent('head.php');

string = " <head> </head>";
$head = str_replace("<head>", "<head>". $headin, $head);
echo $head;
```

Output will be `output string` not `file string` :

```
 <head><title> Hello world </title> </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is pretty basic (you try to hardcore modify - programmerly edit - the template script, right?) but anyway:

```
$file = file('absolut/path/to/file.php');

foreach ($file as $line => $code) {

    if (str_contains($code, '<head>')) {

        $file[$line] = str_replace('<head>', '<head>' . $headin, $code);

        break;
    }
}

file_put_contents('absolut/path/to/file.php', $file);
```